# Is there similar product to eclipse sirius for Visual Studio and .Net?

Tags: eclipse-sirius

**Hello**,
Anyone know a similar tool to eclipse sirius but for .Net and Visual Studio?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is, to my knowledge, no equivalent to EMF in the Dot Net world, I don't expect there is any equivalent to EMF-based technologies such as Sirius, Xtext, etc.